# UITableview cells are overlapping with one another in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios10

My problem is: I have 10 records and displaying them in UITableview with 10 rows. This is working fine in all version below iOS 10 but in iOS 10 all cells are overlapping with one another at top position of tableview (at row 0 position).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
@try
{
    for (UIControl *subview in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    }
    NSString *storedValue, *currValue;
    UILabel *lbl        = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44)];
    switch (headerTag)
    {
        case 0:
        {
           //conditional code
        }
        break;

        case 1:
        {
            //conditional code
        }
        break;

        case 2:
        {
            //conditional code
        }
        break;

        .
        .
        .
        .

        default:
        break;
    }

    lbl.lineBreakMode   = NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle;
    lbl.textColor       = PRIMARY_LABEL_COLOR;
    lbl.backgroundColor = indexPath.row & 1 ? DROPDOWN_SECOND_COLOR : DROPDOWN_FIRST_COLOR ;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];

    if([currValue isEqualToString:stringvalue])
    {
        UILabel *lblTick = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 44, 44)];
        [lblTick setTextColor:PRIMARY_LABEL_COLOR];
        [lblTick setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [lblTick setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:30]];
        [lblTick setText:@"\u2713"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTick];
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    CATCH_NSException
}
return cell;
}
```

I did search on this issue and found so many answers but all are related to xcode 7 and iOS 8 and implemented same but its still not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Show your relevant code

Comment: show your delegate implementation.

Comment: please check code I added.

Comment: It would be great if you add a code of `sizeForItemAtIndex` and data source methods for number of items and number of sections.

Comment: Thayu ke nai :D

Comment: It is just simulator issue. It is working fine in iOS devices. :(

Comment: @AjayGabani  Lol :P